# Time difference in hours between 2 ISO - 8601 compliant dates

Tags: bash, date, date-arithmetic, iso8601

I have 2 dates that are both in ISO - 8061 compliant date format.

```
echo $START
2019-02-14T16:09:13Z

echo $END
2019-02-14T19:43:12Z
```

Now I want to find the time difference between both. I would prefer the difference to be in hours.

What Ive tried is :

```
echo "$(($(date -d "$START" '+%s') - $(date -d "$END" '+%s')))"
```

But it does not work. Any ideas whats the best way to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the [dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/) tools.

Then the answer becomes:

```sh
> datediff 2019-02-14T16:09:13Z 2019-02-14T19:43:12Z -f "%H hours"
3 hours
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "$((($(date -d "$END" '+%s') - $(date -d "$START" '+%s'))/60/60))"
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: Beat me to it, convert to epoch first

Answer (score 0):

On macOS using the built-in BSD `date` a more verbose solution is required:

```
echo "$((($(date -jf '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ' "$END" '+%s') - \
    $(date -jf '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ' "$START" +%s))/3600 ))"
```

Output:

```
3
```

Similar approach to @Cyrus's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54698104/time-difference-in-hours-between-2-iso-8601-compliant-dates#answer-54698419) of converting to epoch first.